# Sublime Text 3: Highlight current line

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using `sublime text 3`. I want to highlight current/active line. I did not find anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add the following setting to your menu `Preferences => Settings - User`

```
"highlight_line": true,
```

Comment: I'd like to know where I could find the "Highlight current/active line" option.

Comment: You can find it in menu under Preferences as mentioned in answer